# Can the speed of a vehicle be determined based upon the extent of injuries to a pedestrian?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, speed

While driving at night in a Prius, at varying speeds of 5-20 MPH in heavy, stop-and-go traffic on a 4 lane city street, two pedestrians in dark clothing were struck (not in a crosswalk). One died of head injuries. One had minor injuries - broken tib-fib. 
The 3 eye witnesses observed contradictory positions of the car and the pedestrians, speed of vehicle, lighting, and where the bodies landed. The police botched the incident report and the accident scene was compromised. 
Can the speed of the vehicle at the actual point of impact be determined by the extent of injuries to the pedestrian or by the number of feet each pedestrian was thrown?

Comment: From the injuries, probably not. From how far each went, you should be able to using Newton's laws and conservation of momentum.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm sometimes wondering about.

Comment: See, for instance, [Accident Reconstruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicular_accident_reconstruction) on Wikipedia.

Comment: @Kyle You'd be more accurate if you combine injury data too. Injury also happens due to conservation of momentum.

Answer (score 1):

You can be sure that at least one reasearch team may help answer your question.
Try to mail them. It seems that one can make such model. But still, as we can see it's a bit probabilistic field.
http://trb.metapress.com/content/v4t5712601175275/

http://www.google.pl/books?hl=pl&lr=&id=dWCbAjlnGzsC&oi=fnd&pg=PR10&dq=pedestrian+injuries+speed+of+vehicle&ots=FGJXWvatMv&sig=-ZQFH6Nk5si5zzgyLtYnqabgExE&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=pedestrian%20injuries%20speed%20of%20vehicle&f=false